# App Crashes after taking long to select image from gallery

Tags: java, android-studio

so I am building a social app which needs images for posts. The problem is when I open the gallery to select an image it crashes. It doesn't crash always it only crashes if I take some time, But not t0o much time just an amount I think would be average in terms of an average person going through his gallery looking for the right image. I have no idea where the issue is because I tried finding an error in the logs but its almost like the crash event is outside the app so the logs don't show it. here is the code to pick the image

```
add_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);

        }
    });
```

Then here is the code for retrieving and compressing the image in onActivityResult of course

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isImageSelected = true;

        try {
            Bitmap original = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, UPLOAD_IMAGE_QUALITY, stream);
            image = stream.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

Comment: Providing more details on the crash, including what type of exception is happening, a stack trace, or a way to reproduce the issue is probably going to be helpful.  Do you even know that the two code snippets above are actually causing the issue?  I am not an Android expert, but I think it's unlikely that most people will be able to divine your issue just based on those two functions and a quick description of the problem.  More context is almost certainly needed.

Comment: @Jake Like I said am not getting any error in my logs but the app is crashing. Am lost too, because there is no error that I can see in the logs its just crashing. I don't mind providing more code on request because I don't know which code to provide